# Subtract one column from another in SAS data step

Tags: sql, sas

I have the below code to subtract the column "Eligible in Store" from the column "Total Count" in SAS. For some reason, this is not working. I'm fairly new to SAS, but this seems like it should be extremely straight forward. I've tried pretty much everything I can think of though, so any help would be appreciated.

```
data Additional_UPCs (drop=_FREQ_);
set Additional_UPCs;

by ut_id;

retain total_count;

if ut_id = 19 then total_count = _FREQ_;
else total_count = total_count;

New_UPCs = (total_count-Eligible_in_Store);


 run;
```

Comment: Your else statement does nothing. Use a diff data set name for output dataset and check your log for errors. Change first line to data test (drop = _freq_); and check the test dataset for results. Edit: you may need to recreate your original data as it's been modified now. This type of coding (same dataset in SET and DATA ) is hard to debug.

Comment: It would help if you showed some data of what your input file looks like and what you would like your output file to look like